Face frame made of plywood or mdf
Cabinets are face frame.  Screwing the hinge to the side of the plywood face frame will most likely fail with time.  My cabinet contractor wants to add a piece behind the face frame, this piece would be flush with the face frame so he could use frameless concealed hinge.  I thinking a 4 screw mount that would have all screws in the new piece of wood would work.  Can you give guidance on the hinge type and dimensions for the holes in the new piece of wood?  Do you think this will work?

This sounds like a good idea to me (27-years cabinetmaker here). Frameless concealed hinges with screw-in plates, like these:

picture source, not an endorsement as such, but my boss used them and they worked well)
These can mount in the side of the cabinet, or as in your proposed case, a block attached behind the face frame. The mounting plate screws are usually 37mm (1 7/16") behind the front of the cabinet face:

Source, edited by me
This should get beyond the usual 19mm (3/4") to 25mm (1") thickness of the cabinet frame and gets the screws into the added block. As long as the block is added firmly, the hinge plate will be firm, too.
You could ask your cabinet contractor to show you a quick mockup, or at least a full-scale drawing, to see what they're planning.

Do you know a make and model number for the concealed hinge?

The particular hinges I am familiar with are "Salice". "Blum" is another I've heard of, and there are other companies. Model numbers may change; talk to your contractor, as they may use a different company's product.

@Triplefault I assume the block is screwed to the side, and the hinge plate is screwed to both?

@Huesmann The block could be screwed to either cabinet side or the frame or both. Some cabinet sides can be rather thin, though, sometimes a mere 1/2" (12mm) sheet stock, which would make screwing to the side somewhat difficult. The bracket I show wouldn't screw into the "end grain" of the frame opening, but there are some brackets that might.
